# Question about Hopkins-Levitzki Theorem's proof

Tags: modules, noetherian, artinian, semi-simple-rings

I am studying the proof of this theorem (of T.Y.Lam). Namely:
Let R be a ring for which rad R is nilpotent, and $R/radR$ is semisimple. Then for any R-module ${}_{R}M$, the following statements are equivalent:

1) M is notherian

2) M is artinian

3) M has a composition series

My question is (1) $\Rightarrow $ (3) and (2) $\Rightarrow $ (3). Here is the proof:

Assume M is either noetherian or artinian. For $J = rad R$, fix an integer n such that $J^n = 0$. Consider the filtration

$$M \supseteq JM \supseteq J^2M\supseteq...\supseteq J^nM = 0$$
It is enough to show that each filtration factor $J^iM/J^{i+1}M$ has a composition series.But $J^iM/J^{i+1}M$ is either noetherian or artinian, as a module over $R/rad R$. Since $R/rad R$ is semi simple, $J^iM/J^{i+1}M$ is a direct sum of simple $R/rad R$ - módules. The chain condition on $J^iM/J^{i+1}M$ implies that this direct sum must be finite, so $J^iM/J^{i+1}M$ does have a composition series as an $R/rad R$ - module. QED

My question is: why $J^iM/J^{i+1}M$ has a composition series as an R-module implies that $M \supseteq JM \supseteq J^2M\supseteq...\supseteq J^nM = 0$ is a composition series? Are each $J^iM/J^{i+1}M$ simple? why?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is not that $M \supseteq JM \supseteq J^2M\supseteq...\supseteq J^nM = 0$ is a composition series, merely that it can be refined to one, which only requires that each of its factors has a composition series.

I should also note this is not the Hopkins-Levitzki Theorem, which states that a ring that is Artinian is Noetherian.

Comment: No, the Hopkins-Levitzki theorem *is* stated this way sometimes. The fact you're alluding to is a corollary.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this refinament can be done. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Oh, I think I see now. Isomorphism theorems are needed. Thank you!

Comment: @CMonsour right Artinian-->$rad(R)$ is nilpotent + $R/rad(R)$ semisimple, therefore $R$ is right Noetherian too.